# CoreData with CloudKit: record types not showing in dashboard

Tags: ios, core-data, cloudkit

I'm adding CloudKit support to my app via NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.

In developer portal, I added iCloud and Push notifications capabilities to my app identifier, downloaded a new provisioning profile and installed it on Xcode. In iCloud I checked "CloudKit support" and enabled a container for my app.

In my app target, Signing & Capabilities, I enabled Remote notifications and CloudKit, and checked the container.

Now I run my app with NSPersistentCloudKitContainer for all my Core Data stuff. I do tasks that create new managed objects. This is on my device on which I'm logged in with iCloud.

In the CloudKit dashboard I see my app's container but I see no evidence that any objects made it to the cloud. I'm on Development, I click on Record Types and I expect to see some of the "CD_..." from my entities. Only the Users record type shows up.

[image]

I reinstalled the app from scratch to see if the objects created earlier synced from the cloud but no, apparently there was nothing there.

Any ideas?

Update: On my device I'm logged in with my personal Apple ID. I'm enrolled in the developer program with that same ID. The app is NOT showing in the list of apps using iCloud.

Comment: If your developer AppleID is not the same as your current AppleID this is normal.

Comment: @vadian I have a single Apple ID, my personal ID that is logged in on my device with iCloud, and I'm enrolled on the developer program with this ID. Am I missing something?

Comment: I meet similar issue, I can't see the new created record. when I switch to private database, the webpage says 'there was a problem with your request'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I'd missed this step while creating the NSPersistentStoreDescription:

```
description.cloudKitContainerOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: "blah")
```

I'm not yet seeing it in the Dashboard because now I get an error about the DB model having incompatibilities with CloudKit! But that's another story.

Answer (score 4):

In the WWDC19 Session, [Using Core Data With CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/202/), they mention that they use a custom zone for apps that use the Core Data/CloudKit integration. In order to see the data, from your CloudKit dashboard, select Private Database, then the custom CloudKit zone that was created for you. From there, select your record type and then Query Records. You should then see your data show up.

Comment: This worked for me! I had to select the zone that was created for me which is named "com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone".

Answer (score 1):

**I had to update an old Objective-C app and struggled for three days** to get CloudKit schema update to work. Sadly, even the Apple docs don't do a thorough job of showing you how to implement in Objective-C.

My problem was that I was using the wrong code to initialize NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions.

**Here's my Objective-C code that actually worked...**

```
    NSPersistentCloudKitContainer* container = [NSPersistentCloudKitContainer persistentContainerWithName:"MyApp"  managedObjectModel:_managedObjectModel];

    NSURL *localStoreURL = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyApp.sqlite"];
    NSPersistentStoreDescription* localdesc = [NSPersistentStoreDescription persistentStoreDescriptionWithURL:localStoreURL];
    //the following line is the piece I couldn't find elsewhere on the Web
    localdesc.cloudKitContainerOptions = [[NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions alloc]  initWithContainerIdentifier:@"iCloud.com.myapp"];
    localdesc.cloudKitContainerOptions.databaseScope = CKDatabaseScopePrivate;

    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = @[localdesc];
    [container loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(NSPersistentStoreDescription *storeDescription, NSError *error) {
      if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load store: %@", error);
        abort();
      }
    }];

#if DEBUG
    NSError *err;
    // The following line will populate the CloudKit Schema RecordTypes ONLY if your device (or simulator) is logged into iCloud!!
    // Use NSPersistentCloudKitContainerSchemaInitializationOptionsPrintSchema if you
    // just want to print out what it will export
    [container initializeCloudKitSchemaWithOptions: NSPersistentCloudKitContainerSchemaInitializationOptionsNone error: &err];
    if (err != nil) {
      NSLog(@"Failed to create schema: %@", err);
    }
#endif
```

I found these links helpful:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/66449534/1148240
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcloudkitcontainer/3343548-initializecloudkitschemawithopti?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

I find out why the schema missing in CloudKit dashboard. You should create a record and save it, in this way you trigger a sync(maybe?) and check the CloudKit dashboard again, you will see the new created schema.